# How do I find this type of starter capacitor? (photo)

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I've searched for the numbers, 2001-42 and TW9569 and not finding anything. How would you go about searching for this type of replacement capacitor?

It came from an American Standard Jacquzzi/whirlpool motor that hums when I try to turn it on. I can't seem to find just this part on their website, they only sell the whole motor for e.g. $200.

[image]

Comment: FYI you may find those large capacitors at shops catering to HVAC repair, as air conditioners often have a capacitor serving the identical function (startup of compressor motor).

Comment: [These](https://www.digikey.bg/en/products/filter/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58?s=N4IgjCBcoCwAwFYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAMwDsNYATFSALrEAOALlCAMqcAnAJYA7AOYgAvsQZwYATmQg0kLHiKkKIBjQB0CAAQBWgGIhiVKsbNsQXHgFURQzgHl0AWXyZcAVwH4UpKSQA) may help. There's no 30uF capacitor in them, but 27u or 33u may work.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  He needs a motor start/ motor run capacitor.  Aluminum electrolytic a rather poor substitute

Comment: @user28910 They are aluminum but not electrolytic, even though Digikey located them intentionally under aluminum electrolytic capacitors. And their intended application is Motor Start. Check the [series datasheet](https://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/PSU.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, what would I need to be concerned about with using under/over 30u? e.g. 27u or 33u. What does the `u` in 30u mean/do?

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/basic_concepts/capacitance/capacitor-conversion-chart-uf-nf-pf.php says Micro-Farad, µF, which as @theodore says, it is the total capacitance. So I guess I am wondering if there would be side effects from using a slightly different capacitance. If I were to error one way or the other, which way is preferrable?

Comment: @Rohat Kilic They are aluminum electrolytic but non-polarized. They are exactly what is needed. A polarized electrolytic would be instant failure not a poor substitute. The 33uF 330V would be my choice,

Comment: Thanks all! I just ordered the 33uF 330V from Digi-Key. AND... I learned a ton from all of these, especially on how to find future capacitors. I also learned that Digi-Key is a popular site buy from. I also found similar capacitors from Grainger, which had 26-30uF and 30-36uF options. I feel comfortable searching for capacitors going forward now! Lastly, I learned that some use the slang "cap" for capacitor, originally I thought it meant a "cap" for the "capacitor".

Comment: 2001-42 may well be the manufacturing date, the 42nd week of 2001

Answer (score 9):

The things you *didn't* search for are all the things you *should have* searched for:

- Capacitance **30µF** (some vendors use uf so you don't have to type the special symbol).
- Voltage **300 VAC**  (It's OK to get one rated for a higher voltage.)
- Temperature limits **-25°C/+70°C**
- Frequency, **50/60 Hz**.  (Probably not an issue if this isn't specified as long as you're selecting a capacitor for motor starting)

You might also need to select the physical size/shape to fit into the enclosure, as well as the termination type.

Comment: This is really useful, I forgot to mention I did search for 300vac but did not search the capacitance, temp limits or frequency.

Comment: Please mention that the voltage can be 300 VAC **or higher**.

Comment: Thanks again, now I am wondering if someone else already used a higher one, and maybe I can get a 240VAC one etc. I am going to try to find the electronic schematic for the motor and see if it is somehow specified.

Comment: I also see a tool called the Capacitor Wizard, which is too pricey for this project right now, but looks like it can determine what capacitor to use if one doesn't know.

Comment: You should never use a smaller one. 240VAC peaks at 340 V, so never go below the ratings that come installed in the device or you're making yourself a fire hazard.

Comment: @WilliamMariager A VAC rating is always given in RMS volts, so the peak voltage is not relevant - a 300VAC rating is good for 300VAC (which itself peaks at 420V).  You should always use *what is specified* unless you're qualified to determine otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Did a little parametric search on digikey.

Not the same, but will work just fine.

[The product i selected](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/epcos-tdk-electronics/B33331V7306J080/495-77224-ND/9086205)

[The parametric search](https://www.digikey.de/products/de/capacitors/film-capacitors/62?FV=mu30%C2%B5F%7C2049%2C-8%7C62%2C1292%7C189716%2C1292%7C193216%2C1292%7C198130%2C1292%7C199507%2C1292%7C219848%2C1292%7C221502%2C1292%7C222858%2C1292%7C224031%2C1292%7C256165%2C1292%7C263523&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)

Comment: Thanks, I just saw in another video that I can use a 460VAC in a 300VAC use case, but no vice versa. So the product you selected (460VAC) should work for my 300VAC use case, right?

Comment: @ElijahLynn No issues with higher voltage rating.

Comment: @ElijahLynn The voltage rating is how much it can take before failing.  A higher voltage rating on a capacitor is never a problem.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - This comment is not for this application, but in response to your statement that "A higher voltage rating on a capacitor is never a problem."  Though generally true, for my low voltage applications (<3V) the significantly higher ESR / DCR of a high voltage capacitor is a problem. It seems we always have to say "it depends..." and I hate making things more complicated, but as Albert Einstein said, “Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler.” So you might say, "A higher voltage rating on the replacement run capacitor is not a problem in this case."

Answer (score 5):

The capacitor pictured is a non-polarized electrolytic motor start capacitor. You can find such capacitors by searching "motor start capacitor." The capacitor selected by @ElectronicsStudent appears to be a metalized polypropylene, motor run capacitor. I believe that a motor run capacitor can be safely substituted for a motor start capacitor (but not vice versa). However, the motor run capacitor will tend to be a bit larger. Motor start capacitors have voltage ratings comfortably above the supply voltage. It is not a good idea to substitute a capacitor with a lower voltage rating than the one that had been used.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the differences between the two. I wasn't sure what to make of the motor run capacitor looking so different so that makes much more sense.